# GridView displays wrong data for last items WinRT

Tags: c#, gridview, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I've got a weird problem where a GridView I have bound to a CollectionViewSource shows the wrong data for the last items. But the actual binding is correct. If I listen for ItemClicked, the DataContext is correct, the UI is just displaying the info for a previous item in the GridView. My goal is to bind to a grouped set of data in a CollectionViewSource, but I've even had it happen if I'm just binding directly to an ObservableCollection.

Here's my XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
<CollectionViewSource x:Name="CuratedCVS" IsSourceGrouped="True"  />
</Page.Resources>

<SemanticZoom Padding="0">
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <GridView x:Name="CuratedFeedsList" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CuratedCVS}}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CuratedFeedItemTemplate}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFeed, Mode=TwoWay}"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              IsSwipeEnabled="True"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
              ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
              Padding="20,0">
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource CuratedFeedHeaderTemplate}"/>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
<SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
    <ListView Background="{Binding SecondaryBackgroundBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeManager}}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CuratedCVS}, Path=CollectionGroups}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CuratedFeedJumpTemplate}"
              Padding="0,10">
    </ListView>
</SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

And here's my code to group my data (which seems to work):

```
var result =
        from f in CuratedFeeds
        group f by f.Category into g
        orderby g.Key
        select g;
    CuratedCVS.Source = result;
```

(Where CuratedFeeds is an ObservableCollection)

Has anyone seen this before? This only happens in a Windows 8.1 app. It works flawlessly in a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

Answer (score 0):

So I discovered what the problem was, and unfortunately it didn't have anything to do with the code I posted. I was customizing the ItemContainerStyle, where I used this:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ListViewItemPresenter Content="{Binding}" Margin="0"
                                           SelectedBackground="{Binding SecondaryBackgroundBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeManager}}"
                                           SelectedForeground="{Binding ForegroundBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeManager}}"
                                           PlaceholderBackground="{Binding BackgroundBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeManager}}"
                                           PointerOverBackground="{Binding SecondaryBackgroundBrush, Source={StaticResource ThemeManager}}"
                                           SelectionCheckMarkVisualEnabled="False"
                                           Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

In this code, the problem was the **Content="{Binding}"**. I don't know why, but this was screwing up the data. All I had to do was remove the **Content="{Binding}"** and it worked perfectly.